# How to create multidimentional array in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I created tables in which each cells will change its class between clicked cells.

When I create this table, I would like to get clicked history `array`.

In the current state,history `array` is stored in `clicked` array.

clicked array is like

`array=[1,4,6,9]`

but My desired result is like

`array=[[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9]]`

or

`array=[[1,4],[6,9]]`

I mean in each class change,I would like to get parent keys for manipulation.

If you have some opinion, please let me know.

```js
const $days = $("td");
 const range = [-1, -1];
 
 let clicked =[];



 $(function() {
  $("td").click(function() { 

  if (range[0] > -1 && range[1] > -1) { // RESET
        range[0] = -1;
        range[1] = -1;
      }
  
      if (range[0] > -1 && range[1] < 0) { // SET END
        
        range[1] = $days.index(this);
        
        $days.slice(range[0],range[1]+1).addClass('is-active');

      }
  
      if (range[0] < 0 && range[1] < 0) { // SET START
        range[0] = $days.index(this);
      }
       
      let clickedID=$days.index(this);
      clicked.push(clickedID);
      console.log("Array of clicked cells",clicked);
      
      
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div {padding: 5px;}

table {border-collapse: collapse;}

.aqua{background-color: aqua;}

td:hover {
background-color:yellow;}

.is-active{
background-color:aqua;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>

<script>
  let html = ''
  html += '<table>';
  let i = 0;
  for (let w = 0; w < 10; w++) {
    html += '<tr>';
    for (let d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
      i = i + 1;
      html += '<td>' + '<div>' + i + '</div>' + '</td>'
    }
    html += '</tr>';
  }
  html += '</table>'
  document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = html;


</script>
```

Comment: Can you give us an idea what the steps are and what the result looks like? Because the code you have does make the clicked cells aqua in sets. So you could just read the aqua cells in start-end order

Comment: Thank you for comment,my goal is to make calendar like tables, and can register range   event for example `aqua cells` in this example, and  next ,`removeClass` of aqua cells by clicking one of them. therefore I would like to get `parent key` in each event. If we can reach `parent key`, we can `removeClass` by clicking one cells between `start` and `end` cells..it like  `const arr = array( 1 => array ( 1, 2, 3 ), 2 => array ( 6, 7)`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this help?

```
let sets = []
  clicked.forEach((item,i) => { 
    if (i===0 || i%2===0) sets.push([])
    sets[sets.length-1].push(item)
  })
```

```js
let html = ''
html += '<table>';
let i = 0;
for (let w = 0; w < 10; w++) {
  html += '<tr>';
  for (let d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
    i = i + 1;
    html += '<td data-layer=0>' + '<div>' + i + '</div>' + '</td>'
  }
  html += '</tr>';
}
html += '</table>'
document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = html;


const $days = $("td");
const range = [-1, -1];

let clicked = [];



$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {

    if (range[0] > -1 && range[1] > -1) { // RESET
      range[0] = -1;
      range[1] = -1;
    }

    if (range[0] > -1 && range[1] < 0) { // SET END

      range[1] = $days.index(this);

      $days.slice(range[0], range[1] + 1).addClass('is-active');

    }

    if (range[0] < 0 && range[1] < 0) { // SET START
      range[0] = $days.index(this);
    }

    let clickedID = $days.index(this);
    clicked.push(clickedID)
    let sets = []
    clicked.forEach((item,i) => { 
      if (i===0 || i%2===0) sets.push([])
      sets[sets.length-1].push(item)
    })  
    console.log("Array of clicked cells", sets);
//    $(".is-active").each((i,td) => console.log(td.innerText))


  });
});
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.is-active {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>
```

Comment: Thanks,My desired result is when I click `1` then `3` then `6`then`9`,`array`like`[1,3],[6,9]`   each cells is becomes `aqua` and sandwitched by start and end cells. is this code reproductive?